# classname::dofunction... what is it? how i use it?

Tags: c++

Every once in a while a programmer will see something like this in her code:

```
classname::dofunction();
```

example:

```
class person
{
private:
    string name ; 

public:
    string getperson() { return name ; }
};

void main()
{
    ............
    .........
    ........

    person::getperson(); 
}
```

I want to use something like the previous example but I get this error:

```
 error C2352:
 'GUI_Window::Get_FrameWindowPtr' :
 illegal call of non-static member
 function
```

1. What is the name of this technique?

   Can you explain about how to use it?

Comment: @user722528: Even though some of us don't really answer questions for acceptance or rep but with intention to just help out, You should consider it your moral responsibility to accept answers that help you solve your problems.

Comment: The question is unclear and shows little research effort.

Comment: @Coda: I don't think the question is unclear but seems OP not clear about intents of what he/she wants to achieve and why?

Comment: @Als: That would mean the same thing. If the OP is not clear about what he wants, that in other words means, the question is not clear :P

Comment: @Nawaz: Those are 2 different things, even if OP is not clear about what is needed. The Q in itself is clear.

Comment: @Als" How is "the question is unclear" and "OP not clear about intents of what he/she wants" different?  Anyway don't want an argument with you, but OP needs to pickup their game, so the question deserves a downvote.

Comment: @Als: Not really in this case. If the question doesn't make much sense, then its not clear. Every English sentence starting with *why*, *what*, *how*  and ends with an "?" doesn't make it a meaningful question :P

Comment: @Coda: Well the Op needs to pick up their game but needs a direction to do so. SO is not about just asking Q's and answering them it is about helping others as well as self learn new and better. I would prefer giving a newbie OP a direction to delve deep than just telling them not to post Q.

Comment: @Nawaz: Please read my comment to @Coda, I believe the Q will close down eventually but I consider giving someone a direction to solve a problem rather important than just closing a Q. Since i already did that I would vote to close the Q now.

Comment: @Als: Nobody suggests that OP should not ask question(s). @Coda only commented the question is not clear, and shows little effort, with which I totally agree.

Comment: Voted to reopen: I think the OP is just confused about C++ syntax.  btw the `class::member` access is not just for static members - I need a chance to answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

```
classname::dofunction() ;
```

Calls the static function `dofunction()` which is inside the class `classname`.

To be able to call a function in this way, your function should be static inside the class, which is obviously not as we can see, So the error.

To address your problems,

1. Why do you want to call the function in that way?

Your idea is flawed because even if you made `getperson()` as static function it cannot access to `name` which is a non static class member. As a rule static functions in a class can access only static class members.

You could just have `getperson()` as a non static member function and call it through object of the class.

```
class person obj;
obj.getperson();
```

You should probably read more about use of `static` keyword in C++ and rethink your idea of having a implementation as you are suggesting.

Answer (score 2):

The example is calling a static method defined in a class.  But in the example that you have provided, `getperson()` is an instance method, not a static method.  It must be called with an object instance, not the class name.

```
class MyClass {
private:
  int _val;

public:

int instanceFunction () {
  return _val;
}

// can't access member data or use 'this'
static int staticFunction () { 
  return 5;
}
}

int main () {
  int val1 = MyClass::staticFunction(); // static call

  MyClass c;
  int val2 = c.instanceFunction (); // instance call
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must declare getperson() as a static method of a class.

```
static string getperson()
{
//definition here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This syntax is true for calling static functions.
Read [this](http://www.codersource.net/c/c-tutorials/c-tutorial-static-functions.aspx) for principles.

Answer (score 0):

The error you get means that you try to call non-static function like a function. Non-static functions need an existing object:

```
person p;
string name = p.getperson();
```

Add `static` keyword to function declation, you'll be able to call it this way:

```
string name = person::getperson()
```

But static function can't, of course, access non-static members.